# Handling empty request bodies for public/private key-based API

Tags: api, security, rest, authentication, hash

I have a standard API set up in which clients are verified by hashing the request body with the private key attributed to the provided public key, and comparing it to the value of `hash` in the query string.

E.g., request body is `"THIS IS REQUEST BODY"`, they would set `hash` as `sha256('THIS IS REQUEST BODY'.PRIVATE_KEY)`, and then the server would do the same thing to validate it.

How can I secure this authentication process if the request body is empty? The hash would be the hashed value of the private key, and could then be re-used for similar "empty" requests by anyone listening to the traffic.

---

I'm assuming that the only answer will be "require content in the request body", but maybe I'm missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First off, don't do `HASH(DATA + KEY)`. There are known vulnerabilities with it. This is precisely what `HMAC` is designed for. So your hash would be:

```
hash = HMAC(sha256, data, privateKey)
```

Now, the typical way of handling your question (how to prevent replay attacks) is by adding a randomizing factor to each request. There are a few ways to do this, but one that works well is a `nonce` based approach. So:

```
nonce = random(16)
now = time()
data = api_data + '|' + nonce + '|' + now
hash = HMAC(sha256, data, privateKey)

apiCall = data '&nonce=' + nonce + '&time=' + now + '&sig=' + hash
```

Then, on the receiving side, you keep track of the list of nonce's seen in the past 30 seconds. If you get one that you've seen, then reject the api call (as that would be a replay attack). If you get one that's more than 30 seconds old, reject the api call.

```
if (now < time() - 30) {
    return false;
} else if (nonceExists(nonce)) {
    return false;
}
addNonce(nonce);

data = api_data + '|' + nonce + '|' + now
myhash = HMAC(sha256, data, privateKey)
if (myhash == hash) {
    return api_data;
}
return false;
```

And then you can purge the databases on nonce's every 30 seconds (on a cron job) or every week, doesn't really matter. Depends on how active your API is.

The key here though is that you want to keep track of the nonce's while they are valid, otherwise you'd be vulnerable to replay attacks...

Answer (score 1):

Why not use timestamp with the request. That will make the messages unique. Either you have time synchronization or you could send the timestamp in in plain text with the request to verify at the server.

Comment: So just have the timestamp required as part of the request body every time? I don't think it necessarily matters if it's a timestamp, I think it could be any old variable. But timestamp does add an extra dimension to authentication, however small.